# Add an off-topic migrate to Chemistry.SE close reason

Tags: feature-request, migration, close-reasons

There are quite a few questions recently which are off-topic here and belong to Chemistry.SE

Should we add that to the migrate options?

E.g. question : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75081/soap-like-chemical-causing-the-water-to-evacuate

Comment: It's not that good a question. As  a Chem mod I'd prefer if it was a bit more detailed before it was posted/migrated.

Comment: @Manishearth, I thought we would usually just migrate it and let the guys on the other site decide whether it was detailed enough. Because closed or not, it shouldn't be on Physics.SE

Comment: Usually, yes, but less so for beta sites. Also, I _am_ "the  guy on the other site" :p

Comment: This is exactly what   I was thinking of posting. +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chemistry is a beta site, and as a rule we shouldn't really be migrating to beta sites. So I don't see this happening. Once Chemistry graduates to full site status, then sure, we can reconsider.

For now, if a question seems like it should be migrated to a beta site, just flag it as off topic or vote to close as off topic if you have sufficient reputation. When the questions accumulates 3 or 4 close votes, a moderator will take care of migration.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I was also going to propose a migrate option to Engineering.SE instead of the off-topic engineering reason, once it started but considering that we cannot migrate to beta sites, that seems like too far away in the future.